# What is the proper way to use Interop in a regular, non Office, application?

Tags: excel, ms-office, vsto, office-interop

The following has been my development strategy for a long time. I divide the Excel applications in two large classes:

(a) Excel does not have to be present: The app may even run in an OS such as Linux, etc. I use 3rd. party Excel libraries. In Windows, I take advantage of resources such as OpenXML or even better: ClosedXML.

(b) Office Applications such as AddIns: Interop.

However, for a rather complex worksheet that is handled by multiple applications, I have decided that it is best to allow Excel itself to do all the work. I have the typical AddIns but am in the process of porting a regular app which used ClosedXML to Interop. As you may see in the following post, some colleagues have had trouble going that route. The missing class Globals seems to present a serious obstacle.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf4b0ca8-9c3b-41df-a24a-b2c195eaee4e/cannot-access-globals-object-from-c-console-application?forum=exceldev

What is the proper way to use Interop in a regular (non AddIn, non Office) application?

TIA

Comment: FWIW any code you're looking at the uses `Globals` is probably VSTO, not "interop". You'd need to be use the VSTO libraries. If you aren't, the code examples won't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public class InteropExcel
{
  private Application excelApp;
  private Workbook    workbook;
  private Worksheet   worksheet;

  internal void createExcelFile(string targetFilepath)
  {
        excelApp         = new Application();
        excelApp.Visible = false;

        workbook         = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
        worksheet        = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

        workbook.SaveAs(targetFilepath);
        excelApp.Quit();
  }
}
```